# Как сравнить две ветки git?

Tags: git, git-diff

Была у меня ветка `develop`, потом мне понадобилось сделать новую фичу и я создал еще одну ветку `hotfix`, и, помимо фичи, в этой ветке я делал еще что-то: Рефакторил общий код и что-то еще.

А теперь фича мне не нужна больше, и нужно удалить эту ветку.

Я хочу посмотреть, чем отличаются две эти ветки, чтобы вспомнить, насколько весомые правки я вносил в код.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> Я хочу посмотреть чем отличаются две эти ветки

```
$ git diff ветка1 ветка2
```

---

полезно бывает для начала посмотреть не сами отличия, а список отличающихся файлов:

```
$ git diff --name-only ветка1 ветка2
```

и тот же список со статусом каждого файла (добавлен/удалён/модифицирован):

```
$ git diff --name-status ветка1 ветка2
```

---

документация: [`man git-diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html).

Comment: `git diff` покажет вам такую простыню, если изменений и комитов было много. В поставленном процессе участвуют такие практики: а) всегда делаем комиты меньше и понятнее, б) смотрим разницу не по всем файлам `git diff`, а по конкретным `git diff -- folder/to/check one/file/to/check/file` **или** запускаем `git whatchanged --stat -p`.

Comment: Обычно людей интересует не разница между ветками, а изменения, которые были сделаны в ветке по сравлению с базовой. Как это сделать смотрите [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/582273/179765)

Answer (score 20):

Если вы находитесь в ветке hotfix введите команду:

```
git diff develop
```

Ещё можно воспользоваться визуальным клиентом, например [TortoiseGit](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit)(Windows) или [gitg](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Gitg?action=show&redirect=Gitg)(Linux).

Answer (score 12):

`Git` предоставляет гибкие инструменты выбора диапазонов фиксаций и сравнивания веток.

Для решения вашей задачи можно использовать синтаксис двух точек. Таким образом, вы, по сути, просите Git включить в диапазон коммитов только те, которые достижимы из одной ветки, но не достижимы из другой. Для примера предположим, что ваша история выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы хотите посмотреть что находится в вашей экспериментальной ветке, которая еще не была слита в основную. Вы можете попросить Git отобразить в логе только такие коммиты, используя запись master..experiment – она означает “все коммиты, которые доступны из ветки experiment, но не доступны из ветки master”. Для краткости и наглядности в этих примерах вместо настоящего вывода лога будут использоваться буквенные обозначения из диаграммы, расположенные в должном порядке:

```
$ git log master..experiment
D
C
```

Для просмотра изменений можно использовать аналогичную конструкцию с командой `git diff`:

```
$ git diff master..experiment
```

При этом можно использовать все стандартные опции для команд `git log` и `git diff` конструкция с двумя точками просто позволяет указать диапазон коммитов, которые должны быть отображены.

**Другие способы указания диапазона комиттов**

**Множество точек**

Запись с двумя точками полезна как сокращение, но, возможно, вы захотите использовать более двух веток для указания нужной ревизии, например, для того, чтобы узнать какие коммиты присутствуют в любой из нескольких веток, но отсутствуют в ветке, в которой вы сейчас находитесь. Git позволяет сделать это, используя символ ^ или опцию --not, перед любой ссылкой, доступные фиксации из которой вы не хотите видеть. Таким образом, следующие три команды эквивалентны:

```
$ git log refA..refB
$ git log ^refA refB
$ git log refB --not refA
```

Этот синтаксис удобен, так как позволяет указывать в запросе более двух ссылок, чего не позволяет сделать синтаксис с двумя точками. Например, если вы хотите увидеть все коммиты, доступные из refA и refB, но не доступные из refC, вы можете использовать одну из следующих команд:

```
$ git log refA refB ^refC
$ git log refA refB --not refC
```

**Три точки**

Последний основной способ выбора ревизий – это синтаксис с тремя точками, который обозначает все коммиты, доступные хотя бы из одной ссылки, но не из обеих сразу. Если вы хотите узнать какие коммиты есть либо в ветке master, либо в experiment, но не в обеих сразу, вы можете выполнить:

```
$ git log master...experiment
F
E
D
C
```

Эта команда снова выводит обычный журнал коммитов, но в нем содержится информация только об этих четырёх коммитах, традиционно отсортированная по их дате.

В таких случаях с командой log часто используют опцию --left-right, которая отображает сторону диапазона, с которой был сделан каждый из коммитов. Это делает данную информацию более полезной:

```
$ git log --left-right master...experiment
< F
< E
> D
> C
```

*P.S. Информация взята из книги [ProGit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) ([ru](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2)). Подробнее об использовании Git можно узнать из нее.*

Answer (score 4):

Обычно мы сравниваем ветки тогда, когда хотим увидеть то, что мы проделали в нашей ветке. Для этого я использую следующую комманду:

```
git diff master...HEAD
```

Покажет изменения одним патчем, которые я сделал в своей ветки.

Для просмотра списка коммитов я использую такой алиас в `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    tree        = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

И потом, чтобы увидеть все коммиты на моей ветке:

```
git tree master..HEAD
```

или так:

```
git tree --left-right master...HEAD | grep '^>'
```

Это если мы стартуем наши ветки от `master`, если вы стартуете ветки, например с `develop`, то, соответсвенно, вы должны делать:

```
git tree develop..HEAD
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы дописали ненужную фичу, но хотите оставить что-то полезное :

```
develop --> hotfix (фича + что-то ещё)
```

Вы можете двигаться дальше *(в обратном направлении)* удалив ненужную фичу. И не забывая ставить всегда коммит.

```
develop --> hotfix (фича + что-то ещё) --> удалили фичу , но оставили что-то ещё
```

Теперь, используя команду `diff` вы сможете увидеть разницу с веткой `develop` :

```
git diff develop hotfix
```

Если всё оставшееся понравилось, можете сделать `merge`, а если ещё нет, то продолжайте в том-же направлении удалять ненужное.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Github Desktop, который можно скачать с самого сайта github. В нём очень удобно в визуальном режиме просматривать разные ветки и сравнивать их между собой.

Comment: `Используйте <Такой-то инструмент для программирования>` — плохой ответ. Если бы Вы написали `Используйте GitHub Desktop`, а затем написали бы, **как** в GitHub Desktop сравнивать 2 ветки, ответ был бы хорошим. Спасибо.

Comment: Где туалет показал а как смыть за собой не объяснил, что есть такие кто не смог разобраться как нажать кнопку сравнить ветки?

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу @aleksandr-barakin, если git diff показывает слишком большую простыню — можно использовать git difftool с параметром --tool=<meld, kdiff3 или что-нибудь ещё>