# Как получить полные имена изменившихся и добавленных файлов относительно двух коммитов?

Tags: git, консоль

Есть два разных коммита из разных веток мне нужно получить только имена (вместе с прямыми или относительными путями) файлов которые изменились или были добавлены относительно этих двух коммитов. Желательно консольный вариант решение этой проблемы.

Comment: дубликат: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554061/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin точно и для коммитов это работает. спасибо

Comment: а ветка — это всего лишь указатель на коммит.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , а разве указатель не на группу коммитов?

Comment: в программе git — нет. ровно на один коммит. branch — плавающий указатель, tag — фиксированный.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а по какому признаку строится дерево?

Comment: у каждого коммита есть предки. как правило — один. у самого нижнего — ноль, у коммита слияния — два и более. так и строится дерево.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin значит у каждого коммита есть еще и указатель на хеш предка? так..

Comment: совершенно верно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо за просвещение. нигде про это не встречал. бардаку конец )

Comment: видимо, вы не прочитали ни одной книги про git (по крайней мере целиком). в описании метки [git](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) есть список литературы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да я урывками из разных мест узнаю про него. полного понимания не было. и все эти рисунки его работы наводили на меня ужас.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin теперь осталось узнать как коммит создает свое отличие от нескольких предков.

Comment: @perfect дерево строится как направленный ациклический граф (в Википедии хорошее описание). У коммита есть указатель на хеш предка или всех предков (у мерж-коммитов два и более предка). Самый первый коммит, разумеется, не имеет предка.

Comment: `как коммит создает свое отличие от нескольких предков` – не очень понимаю вопрос в такой формулировке. Как работает `git diff`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin я так размышляю. изменили файл и гит сразу же вычисляет разницу файла относительно старой версии и сохраняет ее. но это верно для относительно одного предка. а допустим при слиянии мы указали несколько коммитов, как гит вычислит разницу?, если относительно одного коммита такие то изменения а относительно другого другие (для одного и того же файла), ведь получены две версии изменений которые нужно привести к одному виду.

Comment: @perfect отличный вопрос! Если какой-то файл изменился в обеих ветках по сравнению с основой, то git в общем случае не сможет сам решить, что должно получиться. Будет так называемый "конфликт слияния" (merge conflict). Его придется  разрешать вам.

Comment: Где-то у меня был ответ про это, завтра поищу)